# Execution Order of Hierarchical State Machine (HSM) Actions

Tags: uml, diagram, state-machine, fsm

Actually, I want validation about execution order about HSM.
Are there true on picture, below?

[image]

Comment: Quick homework check before loosing points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the question is about the unique transition present in the diagrams

**self transition**

There is no transition to *s2* so it is impossible to be in *s2* when the transition occurs. The transition is external so *s1ExitAction* then *T1TransAction* then *s1EnterAction*

Supposing there is an additional initial pseudo state and a transition from it to *s2* then the execution is the one you indicate.

If we are in *s2* because of a hidden transition which is not from an hidden initial pseudo state then the execution is *s2ExitAction* then *s1ExitAction* then *T1TransAction* then *s1EnterAction*

**external transition A**

Supposing the transition occurs for at least the second time then the execution is the one you indicate, else the transition occurs when being in *s1* and the execution is *s1ExitAction* then *t1TransAction* then *s1EnterAction* then *s2EnterAction*

**local transition A**

Supposing the transition occurs for at least the second time or we are in *s2* because of a hidden transition then the execution is the one you indicate, else the transition occurs when being in *s1* and the execution is *t1TransAction* then *s2EnterAction*

**external transition B**

There is no transition to *s2* so it is impossible to be in *s2* and then it is impossible to do the transition.

Supposing there is an additional initial pseudo state and a transition from it to *s2* then the execution is the one you indicate.

If we are in *s2* because of a hidden transition which is not from an hidden initial pseudo state then the execution is *s2ExitAction* then *s1ExitAction* then *t1TransAction* then *s1EnterAction*

**local transition B**

There is no transition to *s2* so it is impossible to be in *s2* and then it is impossible to do the transition.

Supposing there is an additional initial pseudo state and a transition from it to *s2* or an hidden transition allowing to be in *s2* then the execution is the one you indicate.

**internal transition**

There is no transition to *s2* so it is impossible to be in *s2* when the transition occurs, then the execution is *t1TransAction*

Supposing there is an additional initial pseudo state and a transition from it to *s2* then the execution is the one you indicate.

If we are in *s2* because of a hidden transition which is not from an hidden initial pseudo state then the execution is *s2ExitAction* then *t1TransAction*

Comment: Thanks Bruno. As you said, yellow sate (s2) is active state. Another question; Because there is only one substate inside super state, init pseudo state is required?

Comment: @kaernk I do not see in the standard that in case there is only one sub state then there is an implicit  initial pseudo state and a transition to that state. Note in some diagrams supposing the current state is *s2* because of an hidden transition which is not from an initial pseudo state the execution is not like you said because there is no reason to enter in *s2* so the associated entry action is not done

Comment: @kaernk to be clear I edited my answer to add the case the current state is *s2* but not because of an hidden initial pseudo state and an hidden transition to it but an other hidden transition